# imposing login requirement to visit every resource in twisted web application

Tags: python, twisted

There's a web application developed in twisted. Does anybody mind suggesting me how can i impose login requirement for visiting every page of that application? Psuedo code to do such task is highly appreciated.

Comment: problem solved using decorators

Answer (score 3):

The Twisted documentation includes [an example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/examples/webguard.py) demonstrating the use of `twisted.web.guard` to require HTTP auth before access is granted to a page.

Comment: thanks Jean ... but i solved it implementing decorators in every page's rendering method :)